# expanding UICollectionViewCell on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` that scrolls up vertically, and i want to change item height in tap. In default state, cell have a height of 2/3 screen height. I tried following:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            if let cell = cell as? TutorialCell {
                let attribute = layout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
                attribute?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                               height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
                collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

            }
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Achieve this by `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method `sizeForItemAt`

Declare a variable

```
var selectIndex: Int = -1
```

In your `didSelectItemAt` add this

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectIndex = indexPath.row

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Add an extension for `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let height = (self.selectIndex == indexPath.row ) ?
            UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height :
            (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 2) / 3

        return CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:height)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but i rather preffer to reload specific row and then call scrollToItem with animation.